# nloptr: does lbfgs() need to explicitly provide a gradient function when doing optimization?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, nlopt

In the `nloptr` package, functions like `lbfgs()` seem to need a gradient function. But if I do not provide the gradient function, they also work.

My question is: does `nloptr` automatically calculate the gradient function, or do functions like `lbfgs()` just not need the gradient function?

If the objective function is very complex, can `nloptr` calculate the gradient function automatically, or must it be provided by users?

```
library(nloptr)

## example for auglag()
x0 <- c(1, 1)
fn <- function(x) {
  (x[1] - 2) ^ 2 + (x[2] - 1) ^ 2
}

hin <- function(x) {
  -0.25 * x[1] ^ 2 - x[2] ^ 2 + 1 # hin >= 0
}

heq <- function(x) {
  x[1] - 2 * x[2] + 1 # heq == 0
}
## it works even gr = NULL
auglag(x0, fn, gr = NULL, hin = hin, heq = heq, localsolver = "LBFGS")

gr <- function(x) nl.grad(x, fn)
## it also works, when provide the gradient function.
auglag(x0, fn, gr = gr, hin = hin, heq = heq, localsolver = "LBFGS")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?lbfgs`, we read that this function does indeed automatically compute the gradient if it is not provided:

> gr: gradient of function fn; will be calculated numerically if not
>   specified.

Digging into the source code of `lbfgs`, we see that it does this with the `nl.grad` function:

> ```
> if (is.null(gr)) {
>     gr <- function(x) nl.grad(x, fn)
> }
> ```

From the source code of `nl.grad` (or from `?nl.grad`), it is clear that the function performs [central differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Forward.2C_backward.2C_and_central_differences) to numerically compute the gradient. This approach to estimating the gradient merely evaluates a function of k variables at 2k nearby points, which should work both for simple and complex functions alike.